# angular datatables throws an error

Tags: angular, datatables

I am using angular-data tables to display the data in a tabular format. The table is render in a component which is rendered in a parent as

```
<app-displaytable ></app-displaytable>

<data-table id="info-grid" headerTitle="" [items]="items" [itemCount]="itemCount" >
<data-table-column [property]="'a'" [header]="'Line Number'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
</data-table-column>
<data-table-column [property]="'b'" [header]="'Error Type'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
</data-table-column>
<data-table-column [property]="'c'" [header]="'Field'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true"> 
</data-table-column>
<data-table-column [property]="'d'" [header]="'Value'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
</data-table-column> 
<data-table-column [property]="'e'" [header]="'Description'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">/data-table-column></data-table>
```

I get an error:

> DataTable.html:36 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined
>       at DataTable.get [as substituteItems] (table.component.js:292)

I am sure I am rendering datatable after the "items" are available

Code:

```
<app-displaytable> </app-displaytable>

  <div class="panel-body"  style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; 
         padding-bottom: 0px; overflow-y:scroll; height:400px;" [hidden]="itemCount===0">
    <data-table id="info-grid"  headerTitle="" [items]="items" [itemCount]="itemCount"  >
        <data-table-column [property]="'linenum'" [header]="'Line Number'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
          </data-table-column>
        <data-table-column [property]="'errorType'" [header]="'Error Type'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
        </data-table-column>
       <data-table-column  [property]="'fieldName'" [header]="'Field'"  [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">    
        </data-table-column>
        <data-table-column [property]="'fieldValue'" [header]="'Value'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
          </data-table-column> 
          <data-table-column [property]="'description'" [header]="'Description'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
            </data-table-column>         

      </data-table>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need to show a lot more code. Show the whole component if you can, it's better to have extra if you don't know what's relevant.

Comment: @user7000 someone replied to your question, but you didn't respond. I've updated your question because the formatting wasn't done properly. Your code wasn't visible. Please read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): 'Proof-read before posting!'